# How to export image filenames from Wordpress database?

Tags: mysql, export

I have a Wordpress install that's using about 10,000 images. I'd like to export all filenames used in Wordpress to a file, `filenames.log`

filenames.log would look like this:

`car.jpg
boat.jpg
milf.jpg
car2.jpg
other.jpg`

etc...

The reason I'm doing this is that I have orphaned images in /uploads, and I want to run a delete operation and exclude these filenames that are actually in use.

What command could I run to generate such a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pure MySQL, be sure to correct it for your desired filepath `/tmp/filenames.log`: (Thanks Phil for the select query)

```
"SELECT meta_value AS filename
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
WHERE p.id = pm.post_id
AND p.post_type = 'attachment'
AND meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/filenames.log'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';"
```

Comment: Thank you, and thank you Phil! I ran the above query and got this:

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.7480 sec)

Probably needs some tweak?

Comment: Just checked the /tmp folder and saw that it did in fact generate the file, but the output looks like this `{s:4:"file";s:72:"Diamond-ring-gold-ring.jpg";s:5:"width";s:3:"290";s:6:"height";s:3:"180";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:10:`. I'd like it to output just the filenames without all the extra stuff, how could I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Ok I did some digging around and I found out how to fix it: By adding `AND meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'`. Big thanks to you and Phil!

Comment: @location ok, I've updated answer, feels good to get it figured out, doesn't it?

Comment: It's the best feeling ever. Exporting these names was part 1/2. Now onto part 2/2, which is deleting all images in /uploads except files matching filenames.log.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [Wordpress ERD](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/9/9e/WP3.0-ERD.png) and googling a little, attachments are in the `wp_posts` table, as follows:

```
select *
from wp_posts 
where post_type = 'attachment';
```

Join with `wp_postmeta`, which is a key=>value store, on `meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'` to get the filename (`meta_value`).

So we end up with:

```
select meta_value as filename
from wp_posts p, wp_postmeta pm
where  p.id = pm.post_id
and    p.post_type = 'attachment';
```

Obviously you can filter `meta_value` in the `WHERE` clause to just return `.jpg`s, or whatever.

Comment: I got this when running the code: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.7480 sec) (I don't know if you'll be notified of my comment above. I apologize if this creates a duplicate)